# Add vertical and horizontal line segments to points in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add both vertical and horizontal line segments to points in a graph dynamically. I can do it manually, but with many different point patterns it would take to long. Below is an example dataset i created in R. I'm open to using python or java if there isn't a solution in r as well.

```
df<- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),y=c(2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2),z=c('a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a'))

print(dput(df))


ggplot(df,aes(x,y,color=z))+geom_segment(aes(x = 2, y = 2, xend = 2, yend = 5),color='blue',size=1)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 2, xend = 3, yend = 2),color='blue',size=1)+
  geom_point(size=5)+scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))+
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = 2, label = "2 feet",size=6)+
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = 3.5, label = "3 feet",size=6)
```

[image]

Below is a link to a previous version, but doesn't quite get the viz that i need.

[compute distance and add lines ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453236/compute-distance-and-add-lines-ggplot)

Comment: You should probably just use tags relevant to R. This should be possible and labelling it as an R problem will help others find this question easier.

Comment: okay, I will update.

Comment: Can you provide the dataset in `dput(mydata)` form? Also, what determines the line segments to be added? You need to be much more specific than "...add both vertical and horizontal line segments to points in a graph dynamically"

Comment: I would like to have each point have a connecting horizontal segment and vertical segment. Apologies for the chart not having all the segments drawn.

Comment: Did you mean to include the data from your second example in the prior question, which seems to relate better with the diagram? `df<- data.frame(x=c(1,2,1,3,3,3.5,5,6,5),y=c(2,3.5,6,2,3.5,6,2,3.7,6),z=c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'))`

Comment: Unclear (as avid_useR already stated). You should specify an explicit rule that details how to build the lines. At teh moment it appears ypou only want vertical and horizontal lines and it's not clear what lines should be connecting to the far right green point for instance.